# Font-weight doesn't work for labels in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I have this line in my code:

```
<label style="font-weight: bold" for="sedii18n_codice_paese_indirizzo">Codice paese indirizzo</label>
```

but the label is showed normal.

If I go to the Chrome Inspector I can see this:

```css
font-weight: normal !important;
```

If I change `font-weight` in the inspector the weight of the font is modified normally.

Comment: If there are multiple CSS files linked on the page, it is possible that they are in the wrong order. If I remember correctly, the stylesheet rules that are defined higher up in a page take precedence over those defined later. Reordering the stylesheets may help or may make other rules mess up. Depends how you have structured them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a select tag's option element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element)

Answer (score 11):

Looks like something else is overriding your bold style, hence the !important tag.  Chrome Inspector should tell you where the `font-weight: normal !important;` is being applied.  You can try putting `font-weight: bold !important;` inside your style attribute to override this override.  :-)

Comment: The solution given by Jez should already work on any browser - the problem is not specifically Chrome. The best thing is probably to find out what's applying the `font-weight: normal !important;` in the first place, and see if you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

have you take a look [on the top right corner of your active element in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYnnb.png)?

You can find which stylesheet is overwriting you code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate .css file for label tag and mention  it as below: -

`.lbl { font-weight : normal; }`

Inside html file: -`<label class = "lbl" for="sedii18n_codice_paese_indirizzo">Codice paese indirizzo</label>`

This is working for me as well as overridden in google chrome.