# How do change the color of the text of an <option> within a <select>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of the first option to grey color, that only the text (select one option) but here it's not working here:

```css
.grey_color {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
   <option selected="selected"><span class="grey_color">select one option</span></option>
   <option>one</option>  
   <option>two</option>  
   <option>three</option>  
   <option>four</option>  
   <option >five</option>  
</select>
```

My jsfiddle is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/hUpAB/)

Comment: what about this?
http://jsfiddle.net/hUpAB/1/

Comment: You might also want to just hide the first option entirely:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447134/html-select-how-to-set-default-text-which-wont-be-shown-in-drop-down-list

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Suresh, you don't need use anything  in your code.
What you need is just something like this:

```css
.others {
    color:black
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option style="color:gray" value="null">select one option</option>
    <option value="1" class="others">one</option>
    <option value="2" class="others">two</option>
</select>
```

But as you can see, because your first item in options is the first thing that your select control shows, you can not see its assigned color. While if you open the select list and see the opened items, you will see you could assign a gray color to the first option.
So you need something else in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#select').css('color','gray');
   $('#select').change(function() {
      var current = $('#select').val();
      if (current != 'null') {
          $('#select').css('color','black');
      } else {
          $('#select').css('color','gray');
      }
   }); 
});
```

This is my code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMQeq/).

Comment: Although it works perfectly on the PC (even with screen re-sized).  It did not work on my HTC one phone and nowadays about 40% of browsing is through smartphones.  So be careful.

Comment: Here's the same thing but without the need for extra classes or jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/fMQeq/472/

Comment: No coloring in Firefox on Mac or Linux :-(

Answer (score 23):

I was recently having trouble with this same thing and I found a really simple solution.

All you have to do is set the first option to disabled and selected. Like this:

```html
<select id="select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select one option</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
    <option>five</option>
</select>
```

This will display the first option (grayed out) when the page is loaded. It also prevents the user from being able to select it once they click on the list.

Comment: However, this should only be used for fields that are required. If it is an optional field, then the user cannot reset it to no selection.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add `disabled` as `option` attribute

```
<option disabled>select one option</option>
```

Comment: Only use this for required fields. This makes it impossible for the user to clear the value without reloading the form.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my demo with jQuery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    select{
        color:#aaa;
    }
    option:not(first-child) {
        color: #000;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val()=="") $(this).css({color: "#aaa"});
            else $(this).css({color: "#000"});
        });
    }); 
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<select>
    <option disable hidden value="">CHOOSE</option>
    <option>#1</option>
    <option>#2</option>
    <option>#3</option>
    <option>#4</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/monster75/cnt73375/1/

Comment: This will not be useful if you select option #1 and then you need to select the default option again.

Comment: we can add disabled="disabled" on the default option so user cannot select the default option again, and the default option will act as a placeholder

Answer (score 2):

You can use `optgroup` around `option` in the `select`. It is easy to add colors to option

```css
.type_slct {
  color: #17b3cc
}

.type_slct option {
  color: #1e293b
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
  <optgroup label="Type" class="type_slct">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="">Question</option>
    <option value="">Feature Request</option>
    <option value="">Refunds and Returns</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: For future posts, please [edit] instead of commenting to update your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try just this without the span tag:

```
<option selected="selected" class="grey_color">select one option</option>
```

For bigger flexibility you can use any JS widget.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select id="select">
    <optgroup label="select one option">
        <option>one</option>  
        <option>two</option>  
        <option>three</option>  
        <option>four</option>  
        <option>five</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

It all sounded like a lot of hard work to me, when optgroup gives you what you need - at least I think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have HTML code inside the options, they can only contain text, but you can apply the class to the option instead:

```
<option selected="selected" class="grey_color">select one option</option>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hUpAB/9/

Note:

- The support for styling options varies between browsers. In modern brosers you generally can expect support for coloring but not for font size. A browser in a phone for example usually doesn't display the options in a dropdown, so the styling would not be relevant at all.
- You should not have `html` and `head` tags in the HTML code in jsfiddle.
- You should name your classes for what the represent, not how they look.

Comment: this does not color grey the "select one option" when loading page. how can this be done?

Comment: @Matoeil: Try setting the color of the `select` element.

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: @doublejosh: That is not correct. I tested it right now in Chrome, and it works as described. What browser did you test it in, and what happens exactly?

Comment: Tested again, this doesn't work in Chrome, Safari, or iOS Chrome or iOS Safari. The way that works is `<option disabled value="">Select one</option>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var defaultVal =  $("#select").attr('data-default');
  $("#select option").each(function()
  {
      var optVal = $(this).val();
      if (optVal == defaultVal) {
         $('#select option.others').css({'color':'black', 'font-weight':'bold'});
      } else {
        $('#select').css('color','gray');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" data-default="1">
    <option value="null">select one option</option>
    <option value="1" class="others">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input_field {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  /* padding: 0 0 0 16px; */
  border-radius: 9px;
  outline: none;
  /* background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e500; */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.83, 0.66, 1);
}

.selected {
  color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<select class="selected input_field">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please describe what you have changed and how it impacts the end result so that everyone can understand it

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is working for me

```
.custom-select:hover:not(:disabled),
.custom-select:focus:not(:disabled),
.custom-select:active:not(:disabled){
  color: black;
}

  select{
    color: gray;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can change color optgroup and options use this code:

```css
optgroup { 
    color: red; 
} 
option { 
    color: black; 
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <optgroup label="Last Used Projects">
        <option>APOP Admin Website</option>
        <option>APOP Categorization</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```