# how to give style to the selected option in html

Tags: html, css

I have this mark us

```
<div class="styled-offer">
  <select style="font-size:13px;" class="select offer-select" name="type">  
    <option selected="" class="selected" value="1">Sell Offers</option>
    <option value="2">Buy Offers</option>
    <option value="3">Products</option>
    <option value="4">Companies</option>
    <option value="5">Business Directory</option>
    <option value="6">Classified</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now here you can see the first option which is selected is Sell Offers. Now I want the selected option should be in red color and all rest of options should be in black color. Just like [this](http://www.alibaba.com/) site. Here you can see the option products is by default blue in color and when you click on the options they are black in colors. So I just want this. I want to make it in css. Not in jQuery. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

**Update**
Sorry..I can't change my markup So kindly guide me in this markup...

Comment: pls refer this link ur question smiler to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-select-options-texts

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. The site you're linking to stores the current selected option in a span (which can be styled) and only show/hide the <select> item when the user presses the down arrow. You have to use JavaScript.

Comment: You could change the color of the whole thing on `:focus`, which would give a similar effect: http://jsfiddle.net/rTgsX/1/. Focused, it is one color, but blurred (and closed) it is another color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey thanks all for all of your answers but finally I got the solution. It was damn easy...
My markup was like this

```
<div class="styled-offer">
  <select style="font-size:13px;" class="select offer-select" name="type">  
    <option selected="" class="selected" value="1">Sell Offers</option>
    <option value="2">Buy Offers</option>
    <option value="3">Products</option>
    <option value="4">Companies</option>
    <option value="5">Business Directory</option>
    <option value="6">Classified</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now my css will be like this..

```
<style type="text/css">
  .styled-offer select.offer-select {
    color: #F00;
  }
  .styled-offer select.offer-select option {
    color: #333;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply your CSS class "selected" to a `span`, rather to the `option` itself:

```
<option selected="" value="1"><span class="selected" >Sell Offers</span></option>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I can't hange the markup as because it is generated from the loop. So is there any way to do in css?

Comment: Try this CSS: 
select.offer-select option.selected {color: #f00;}

Comment: thanks for the reply but have you gone through my question and reference link? I want my selected option to be in red color not the options when I will click on them. The default option will be in blue color just like the reference link.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index.html
```

if u are using default drop down it is not possible try custom drop down.try this link it might helpful.