# How to change the text color of first select option

Tags: html, css, select, input

I have a select element which has several items. I want to change the color of its first item, but it seems the color only shows
when you click on the select dropdown. What I want is to change the color (like gray) when the page is loaded so users can see the first option color is different.

See the example here...
http://jsbin.com/acucan/4/

css:

```
select{
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: green;
}
select option { color: black; }
select option:first-child{
  color: green;
}
```

html:

```
<select>
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. The items are only visible when the menu is open. So how what is wrong about your solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do change the color of the select box's option text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/how-do-change-the-color-of-the-select-boxs-option-text)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What about this:

```css
select{
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: green;
}
select option { color: black; }
select option:first-child{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

http://jsbin.com/acucan/9

Comment: Amazing! Never thought about that, Thank you :)

Comment: how do you change the color to black once an option is selected?

Comment: all `<option>` have the `color:black` for me. (Chrome/Mac)

Comment: chrome/windows is working fine, but i'm unable to test on my mac at the moment. Try changing it to `select option:first-child{
  color: green !important;
}`

Comment: To make this work in Webkit browsers on the Mac (Chrome and Safari), you'll need to disable the chrome for the select using `-webkit-appearance:none`. Of course, that will enable the style, but will remove all the rest of the select chrome as well, so you'll need to restyle everything else in the element as well. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wFP44/1/

Comment: I wonder if having to change grandparent / grandchild styles and parent styles to different things has a name....

Comment: select { color: green } makes them all green. option:first-child { color: green } is useless and doesn't do anything.

chrome  55.0.2883.95 on Mac.

Comment: @keif did you check the jsbin link? still works for me on chrome 55

Comment: @jzm I did not! The jsbin link works appropriately, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @sQuijeW That is exactly what I want to know. Does anyone have any hint to this?

Comment: @JohnnyThan change the select (not first-child) color to black. in my code i had it as green.

Comment: Both options are green. Mac - Google Chrome.

Answer (score 42):

If the first item is to be used as a placeholder (empty value) and your select is `required` then you can use the `:invalid` pseudo-class to target it.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  color: black;
}

select:invalid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="">Item1</option>
  <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
  <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This also coloured the valid options in the list for me. I was able to keep the expected color with a `select:invalid option:not(:disabled) { color: black }` rule

Comment: This is a really smart way to solve this problem! Thanks. Worked perfectly

Comment: Why do we need `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button`?

Comment: The default appearance will ignore the color change as it displays the element using platform-native styling.

Answer (score 9):

For Option 1 used as the placeholder:

```
select:invalid { color:grey; }
```

All other options:

```
select:valid { color:black; }
```

Comment: Best answer so far.

Comment: This work for me. Best answer!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way so that when you select an option, it turns black. When you change it back to the placeholder, it turns back into the placeholder color (in this case red).

http://jsfiddle.net/wFP44/166/

It requires the options to have values.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
return $(this).css('color', 'black');
  } else {
return $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```css
select{
  color: red;
}
select option { color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="">Pick one...</option>
<option value="test1">Test 1</option>
<option value="test2">Test 2</option>
<option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using CSS: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMAWt/)

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Text 1</option>
    <option>Text 2</option>
    <option>Text 3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select option:first-child { color:red; }
```

Or if you absolutely need to use JavaScript (not adviced for this): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USdjj/)

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("select option:first-child").addClass("highlight");
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight { color:red; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work in Chrome 60 (pc), even with the !important modifier added

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted this (placeholders should look the same for text boxes as select boxes!) and straight CSS wasn't working in Chrome. Here is what I did:

First make sure your select tag has a `.has-prompt` class.

Then initialize this class somewhere in `document.ready`.

```
# Adds a class to select boxes that have prompt currently selected.
# Allows for placeholder-like styling.
# Looks for has-prompt class on select tag.
Mess.Views.SelectPromptStyler = Backbone.View.extend
  el: 'body'

  initialize: ->
    @$('select.has-prompt').trigger('change')

  events:
    'change select.has-prompt': 'changed'

  changed: (e) ->
    select = @$(e.currentTarget)
    if select.find('option').first().is(':selected')
      select.addClass('prompt-selected')
    else
      select.removeClass('prompt-selected')
```

Then in CSS:

```
select.prompt-selected {
  color: $placeholder-color;
}
```

Comment: How it should work? Can you make an example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the fancy way with pure css would be more expensive; let's see with ES6

```
CSS
select{color:#AE1250}

JS
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach((s) => {
    s.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
    s.style.color=s.value==''?'#AE1250':'#fff';});            
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works on Chromium and change the color to black once an option is selected:

```
select {
  appearance: none;
}

select:invalid {
  color: green;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Copy below jQuery script in your HTML:

Note: All options must have a value and the value of the first option must be empty(value="").

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").each(function (i, select) {
        SetSelectColor(select);
    });
    $("select option").css('color', 'black');
    $("select option:first-child[value='']").css('color', '#999999');
    $("select").change(Select_Changed);    
});

function Select_Changed() {
    SetSelectColor(this);   
}

function SetSelectColor(select) {
    var value = $(select).val();
    $(select).css('color', value != '' ? 'black' : '#999999');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">Please select an option ...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```