# how to change color of specific item on dropdown list when it's only active

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

please tell me a way to change the color of the 1st  tag when it's actived on dropdown.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="cars">
    <option id="choose" value="choose">please choose</option>
    <option value="saab">Asia</option>
    <option value="fiat">Africa</option>
    <option value="audi">Europe</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

-CSS- 
#choose.active{
    background: #red !important;
}
```

Please see the attached jpeg below.

I tried using css but when i change it's color all other items active status colors also changed.[This is what I want.see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EQ8p.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608880/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-first-select-option

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean when it's hovered.

It should be #choose:hover

Avoid using !important