# Make First option as gray and other as black in Select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is my code which is working fine in Firefox 68.0.2 but not on Chrome 76 and Safari 12.1.2. Let me know a workaround or what I am doing wrong here.

I want to make the first select option as gray and rest of the option as black.

Code -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="") $(this).css({color: "#aaa"});
    else $(this).css({color: "#000"});
  });
  
});
```

```css
select{
  color:#aaa;
}
option:not(first-child) {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="">Please select and option</option>
 <option>#1</option>
 <option>#2</option>
 <option>#3</option>
 <option>#4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `option { color: #000 } option:first-child { color: #aaa }`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Accepted answer in the link you attached is keeping all text in same color

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/5nme6jux/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608880/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-first-select-option

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Open your JSFiddle in Firefox and see its not working ..the First option remains black on selection

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS

```
select{
      color:#aaa;
    }
    option{
      color:#000;
    }
    option:first-child {
      color: #aaa;
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="") $(this).css({color: "#aaa"});
    else $(this).css({color: "#000"});
  });
  
});
```

```css
select{
  color:#aaa;
}
option{
  color:#000;
}
option:first-child {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="">Please select and option</option>
 <option>#1</option>
 <option>#2</option>
 <option>#3</option>
 <option>#4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `color` property of `option:first-child` as grey and others are black. Like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="") $(this).css({color: "#aaa"});
    else $(this).css({color: "#000"});
  });
  
});
```

```css
select option { color: black; }
select option:first-child{
 color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="">Please select and option</option>
 <option>#1</option>
 <option>#2</option>
 <option>#3</option>
 <option>#4</option>
</select>
```