# Using HTML <strong> tags inside <select>. Is it possible?

Tags: html

Is it possible make a word using the html tag in this piece of code?

```
echo "<select>";
echo "<option ><strong><em>carro</em></strong></option >";
echo "<option >car</option >";
echo "<option >apple</option >";
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: why in god's name wouldn't you just use `<b></b>`, or use CSS

Comment: Is it possible make a word using the html tag in this piece of code? what do you mena exactly??

Comment: assuming you tried and it didn't work, you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: @greener it's an actual duplicate of that one ;)

Comment: @webeno you don't say..

Comment: I believe the answer is that you cannot. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: @greener I do say! :)

Comment: @myfunkyside According to the HTML5 specification, the `<b>` tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate.

Comment: oh, didn't know that, okay. Although to be honest, I think `<strong>` and `<em>` are so old they're close to being deprecated. I think HTML5 specs would prefer if you use CSS

Comment: @myfunkyside `<strong>` and `<em>` have specific semantic meanings and are interpreted in different ways by assistive technology such as screenreaders. The `<p>` and `<form>` elements are also "old", and I can't see them being deprecated any time soon.

Comment: alright alright, never mind me

Comment: Hi folks, I forgot to saw, I am using bootstrap. I could use css to do that. but I am tried to change the word behavior trough <strong> boostrap3 tag.

Comment: Hi  myfunkyside, <b></b> doesnt work either. Dispite your commnt "I think <strong> and <em> are so old they're close to being deprecated"  it still in use in Bootstrap3 . http://getbootstrap.com/css/ See Inline text elements

Comment: I think this is the only solution. I must use javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-select-options-texts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use HTML tags inside an `option` element, since its content is by [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION) plain text.

This answers the question asked. If the intent was to ask how to style `option` elements or their parts, then there are several old questions on such issues at SO. Styling parts is impossible. Styling an entire `option` element may or may not be possible using CSS, depending on browser.