# How can I style drop-down menus in an email?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the code below, but it doesn't allow for formatting, and it doesn't allow the content underneath the drop items to shift down in an e-mail.

```
<select>
  <option value="first">First-time Vanguard Events app users:                              </option>
  <option value="download">&#8226; Download the Vanguard Events app to your Apple or Android device</option>
  <option value="allow">&#8226; Please make sure to allow push notifications from the app.</option>
  <option value="launch">&#8226; Launch the Vanguard Events app and find Connect Fall 2015 Sales Conference.</option>
  <option value="enter">&#8226; Enter the event code <strong>2015fall</strong> </option>
  <option value="login1">&#8226; To log in, look to the left side of your screen. </option>
  <option value="login2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;If you're using your smartphone, tap on the three horizontal lines</option>
  <option value="login3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;in the upper left corner, which will reveal a link for logging in.</option>
  <option value="login4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To log in on a tablet, tap on the "Log in for more features" in the upper left corner.</option>
  <option value="enter">&#8226; When logging in, enter your name or email and the Cvent confirmation code, XXXXX</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This isn't code this is just text

Comment: Form support, in general, in email clients is pretty poor. You're better off linking to a regular webpage and letting them open it in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. Don't use form controls in e-mail html.
2. [Styling `option`s doesn't work all to well / isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26187466/419956).

The answer to your actual problem is to rethink your setup. Commenters have already pointed out one solution: link to an actual web application in your e-mail. Even so, you'd need to replace your `select` controls with something like the [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [select2](https://select2.github.io/) libraries.