# Change option colour in select menu

Tags: css, html

This might be basic but I'm can not get this working. In my submit form I've got a select menu. I've disabled the first option and set its value to empty.

```
<select  name="types">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select<option>
    <option value="Fruit">Mangos</option>
    <option value="Veggies">Beans</option>
</select>
```

how can I make the text of the disabled option to be `#f60`? Basically I need it to look same as a placeholder text.

Comment: This might be helpful in your case. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-select-options-texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding color using **css** for the `first child` of select list as below

```
<style>    
select option:first-child {
        color : #F60F60;
    }
</style>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhLxgzmv/1/)**

```
select option:disabled {
    color: #f60 !important;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<select  name="types">
    <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Mangos</option>
    <option value="Veggies">Beans</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put background-color on the option tag and not the select tag...

```
select option {
margin:40px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

}

If you want to style each one of the option tags.. use the css attribute selector:

```
   select option {
    margin:40px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

select option[val="1"]{
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
}

select option[val="2"]{
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
}

...
```