# Gravity forms Select Placeholder styling

Tags: css, forms, select, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity forms select field (dropdown) where i want to style the placeholder only. I hope someone can help me.

The form produces the following code:

```
<select name="input_10" id="input_4_10" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="11">
 <option value="" selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">Type of Business</option>
 <option value="Media">Media</option>
 <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
 <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
 <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I want the gf_placeholder to have a different font-color and weight then the actual options. I've tried several things, but either it changes all the options or none. What am i missing? I think it has something to do with the dom. This is the scss that changes the correct item as soon as you open the dropdown:

```
.ginput_container_select select:first-child  {
    color:  $placeholder-color;
    @include font-size(16);
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

But as soon as you close the dropdown it goes back to the unstyled version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-select-options-texts hope this will help you..

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem. Could you solved it finally? Tks!

Comment: Unfortunately not with only css... You could however try a javascript approach.

Comment: I ve got the solution  :
It's simple:
To change the color of the font in placeholders gravity form, you have to use CSS like this:
How does it works? Gravity Form documentation target the ofrm ID by the part after the first field :
#form_wrapper_8 -->> 8 is the number of your form.
If your form is 2 write : #gform_wrapper_2

Now the CSS:
#gform_wrapper_8 .gform_fields .gfield input::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: pink;}

Answer (score 1):

To apply Placeholder Styling on all your forms

```
/* Other Fields */
.gform_wrapper .gform_fields .gfield input::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #ffffff;}

/* Paragraph Text Area */
.gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields .gfield textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that one wants to change the placeholder to the color `#555555`, and one has the following fields: `Name`, `Email`, `Phone`

[image]

For that, the following will do the work

```
.gfield input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: #555555;
}
```

If one has a paragraph text, such as

[image]

Then one will need to use

```
.gfield textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #555555;
}
```