# Change the drop-down selection colors in Materialize?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, materialize

How do I change the drop-down selection colors in Materialize? I can't find in the Materialize docs on how to change this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option  value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Fan</option>
            <option value="2">DJ</option>
        </select>
        <label>Account Type</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the problem here is with the lack of MaterializeCSS API rather it is related to option tag in general.

This solution to a similar question might help which is for vanilla css with jQuery: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635403/5194107)