# Individually color code ToDo cells, not just change everything

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have created a basic to-do list. I want to add the option to color code, similar to Google Keep (this is an exercise). I have tried simply putting one HTML select in, as you can see in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55u6m8em/7/) but this changes the background of that entire section.

```
<p display="none">
  <section class="main" style="display: block;" >
    <div data-bind="visible:todos().length>0">
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:markAll"/>
      <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label>
      <br /><br />
      <select id="colorOptions" id="toggle-all"></select>
    </div>
    <ul id="mycell" class="todo-list" data-bind="template:{ name:'item-template',foreach: todos}">
    </ul>
  </section>
</p>
```

Question: How do I add an option to individually color code the to-do items?

Comment: Post your code in your question. See [mcve]

Comment: OK, will do..@j08691

Comment: @NOOB I changed the broken link.

Comment: @NOOB the issue what you have is, that you add the background to the `<ul>` and not to the `<li>`.

Comment: Because I am not very familiar with templates, would you be interested in a solution without the template?

Comment: Sure! @Thanasis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did it using the templates. First I added the selection for the colors inside the template in the li, so that every entry has a selection. Then I added an id for every selection (which is the order variable, the first `<select>` has the id="0" the second has the id="1" and so on) in order to differentiate them and to make each of them have different functions onchange. I also made the addColorsOptions function which adds the options on every selection when it is created using its unique id.

```js
$(function(){
    var Todo = function(id, title, done, order,callback) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(id);
        self.title = ko.observable(title);
        self.done = ko.observable(done);
        self.order = order;
        self.updateCallback = ko.computed(function(){
            callback(self);
            return true;
        });        
    }
    
    var viewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.todos =  ko.observableArray([]);
        self.inputTitle = ko.observable("");
        self.doneTodos = ko.observable(0);
        self.markAll = ko.observable(false);

        self.addOne = function() {
           var order = self.todos().length;
           var t = new Todo(order, self.inputTitle(),false,order,self.countUpdate);
           self.todos.push(t);           
           self.addColorsOptions(order);
        };
        
        self.createOnEnter = function(item,event){
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && self.inputTitle()){
                self.addOne();
                self.inputTitle("");
            }else{
                return true;
            };           
        }
        
        self.toggleEditMode = function(item,event){
            $(event.target).closest('li').toggleClass('editing');
        }
        
        self.editOnEnter = function(item,event){
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && item.title){
                item.updateCallback();
                self.toggleEditMode(item,event);
            }else{
                return true;
            };           
        }

        self.markAll.subscribe(function(newValue){
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.todos(), function(item) {
                return item.done(newValue);
            });        
        });

        self.countUpdate = function(item){
            var doneArray = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.todos(), function(it) {
                return it.done();
            });
            self.doneTodos(doneArray.length);
            return true;
        };
        
        self.countDoneText = function(bool){
            var cntAll = self.todos().length;
            var cnt  = (bool ? self.doneTodos() : cntAll - self.doneTodos());
            var text = "<span class='count'>" + cnt.toString() + "</span>";
            text += (bool ? " completed" : " remaining");
            text += (self.doneTodos() > 1 ? " items" : " item");
            return text;
        }
        
        self.clear = function(){
            self.todos.remove(function(item){ return item.done(); });
        }
        
        
        self.addColorsOptions = function(id){
            
            var colors = [{
        display: "light yellow",
        value: "ffffcc"        
    }, {
        display: "light blue",
        value: "ccffff"
    }, {
        display: "light green",
        value: "ccffcc"
    }, {
        display: "gray",
        value: "cccccc"
    }, {
        display: "white",
        value: "ffffff"
    }];
    
    var options = ['<option value="">Select color</option>'];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
       options.push('<option value="');
       options.push(colors[i].value);
       options.push('">');
       options.push(colors[i].display);
       options.push('</option>');       
    }
    
    $("#" + id).html(options.join('')).change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val){
        $("#" + id).closest('li').css('backgroundColor', '#' + val);
        }
    });
            
            
        }
        
        
     };
    
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); 

})
```

```css
body {
 font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #3c6dc5;
 color: #333333;
 width: 520px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#todoapp {
  background-color: #3c6dc4;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#todoapp h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
 text-align: center;
  color:white;
}

#todoapp input[type="text"] {
 width: 466px;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 6px;
  color:#000033;
}

.main {
 display: none;
}

.todo-list {
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
  color: #E0E0EF;
}


.todo-list li {
 padding: 18px 20px 18px 0;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.todo-list li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.todo-list li .edit {
    display: none;
}
.todo-list li.editing {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #778899;
}

.todo-list li.editing .view {
 display: none;
}
.todo-list li.editing .edit {
 display: block;
 width: 444px;
 padding: 13px 15px 14px 20px;
 margin: 0;
}

.todo-list li.done label {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}


.todo-list .destroy {
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 20px;
 display: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

#todoapp footer {
 display: none;
 margin: 0 -20px -20px -20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #555555;
 background: #f4fce8;
 border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
 padding: 0 20px;
 line-height: 37px;
}

.todo-count {
    float:left;    
}

.todo-count .count{
    font-weight:bold;    
}

#clear-completed {
 float: right;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 color: #555555;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 padding: 0 10px 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
label{color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todoapp">
    <header>
      <h1>Fun To Do!</h1>
      <input id="new-todo" type="text" placeholder="Finish Homework..." data-bind="value:inputTitle,event: { keyup: createOnEnter}"/>
    </header>

    <section class="main" style="display: block;" >
   
      <div data-bind="visible:todos().length>0">
      
      <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:markAll"/>
          <label for="toggle-all">Mark all as complete</label> <br /><br />
      </div>
      <ul id="mycell" class="todo-list" data-bind="template:{ name:'item-template',foreach: todos}">
      </ul>
    </section>
    
    <footer style="display: block;">
      <div data-bind="visible:todos().length>0">
        <div class="todo-count"><b data-bind="text:todos().length"></b> items left</div>
        <!-- ko if: doneTodos() > 0 -->
          <a id="clear-completed" data-bind="click:clear">
              Clear <span data-bind="html:countDoneText(true)"></span>.
          </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <br style="clear:both"/>
      </div>
    </footer>
</div>
          
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <li data-bind="event:{ dblclick :$root.toggleEditMode},css : {done:done() }">
        <div class="view" >
          <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:done"/>
          <label data-bind="text:title"></label>
          <a class="destroy"></a>
        </div>
        <input class="edit" type="text" data-bind="value:title,event: { keyup: $root.editOnEnter}" />
        <select data-bind="attr: {'id': id}"></select>
    </li>
</script>
```

You can also see the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/55u6m8em/15/).

For any question feel free to comment. I hope this was helpful :)

**EDIT**

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55u6m8em/29/) for the `<input type="color">` addition.

Comment: Thank you for the code and explanation! This is perfect!

Comment: Quick question- any idea how to make the select options the color they describe?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is accomplished. You can check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-select-options-texts). The examples didn't work for me, but you can test it too. Let me know if this was what you wanted, and if it worked, or you have any questions.

Comment: A different idea: we can use <input type=color>to choose background. But now I have the same problem I did before. I think I'll just draft a new question...

Comment: Oh input type=color is good. See my edit, I implemented it in the code and posted JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your fiddle code. There is some unwanted code (that i did not find) that fade out your `div databind="....`. So to remove this problem you can add this at the end of jquery codes before last `});` to see some thing like this:

```
   $('div').show(); //adding code
});
```

Now the select works and you can see the changes in page inspector, But you can not see that here because **your ul is empty**. To see the result change that ul with an static data ul like this:

```
<ul id="mycell" class="todo-list">
   <li>first</li>
   <li>second</li>
</ul>
```