# How to change text color based on specific option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the first option's color to #ccc, others remain #000, but it doesn't work.Why? thanks.
 I don't wnat to use change function, which I think it's unnecessary.

something like this:
[image]

HTML:

```
  <select id="continent"> 
      <option value="-1">continent</option> 
      <option value="1">US</option> 
      <option value="2">UK</option> 
  </select>
```

JS:

```
$("#continent option[value='-1']").css('color','#ccc');
```

Comment: change function is necessary how will you know that option one is selected without the change function?

Comment: just the first option's color not the select one

Comment: add inline style but color will only be applied on the option `<option value="-1"style="color:#ccc">continent</option> `

Comment: did you tried `$("#continent option:first").css('color','#ccc');` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do change the color of the select box's option text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/how-do-change-the-color-of-the-select-boxs-option-text)

Comment: @guradio tried, not work wired

Comment: just set `<option disabled value="-1">continent</option>` and that will gray it out for you.

Comment: it will work only on option not after you selected it will show as black in the select

Comment: @Dejan.S I am not able to select if disabled

Comment: @MilanChheda not working

Comment: you need a change function to apply the color to select and remove depending on the option selected

Comment: what are you trying to do? Do you want it always to be `#ccc` or do you want the selected to be gray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#continent").change(function(){
    $("#continent").val() == "-1" ? $("#continent").css("color", "red") : $("#continent").css("color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="continent"> 
    <option value="-1">continent</option> 
    <option value="1">US</option> 
    <option value="2">UK</option> 
</select>
```

Remember to preset the color of the default option

Answer (score 1):

here is solution

```
$('.mySelect').change(function () {
     if($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")==2){
    $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
    }else{
     $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'blue');
    }

});
```

In above code i use **.find()** method which is used for select child of selected element [try this code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubham52525/zNTqm/1105/)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use jQuery? This can be done with pure CSS.

```css
#continent option {
  background-color: white; /* on XFCE the default background-color is #CCC! */
}
```

```html
<select id="continent"> 
    <option value="-1" style="color:#cccccc">continent</option> 
    <option value="1">US</option> 
    <option value="2">UK</option> 
</select>
```

**However** you probably shouldn't do this, because it looks like the option was disabled, but it isn't. This is counterintuitive and against usability.

Apart from that, it looks different on other operating systems. This is how the snippet from above looks like on ubuntu with XFCE:

[image]

And this is what another solution looks like that also changes the color of the `<select>` to light gray if the 1st option is selected:

[image]

That's why you should either use `<option value="-1" disabled>` or another color.