# How to change font color of the option select of specific divs?

Tags: html, css

How can I change the 2nd child of the option select with id "order" to green? The code I have below applies to all option select which is not preferable based on what I need. Is this doable?

```
<style>
    select option:nth-of-type(2){
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<select id="order"/>
  <option value="">1</option>
  <option value="">2</option>
  <option value="">3</option>
</select>
<select id="type"/>
  <option value="">A</option>
  <option value="">B</option>
  <option value="">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do change the color of the select box's option text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/how-do-change-the-color-of-the-select-boxs-option-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: solve this problem using hover

Comment: Not duplicate. My question pertained to a specific div whereas other questions apply to all div.

Comment: It doesn't interfere you to specify some child you want... Anyway, it requires to represent your options as divs, because options are always shown according to browser style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this and assign your CSS classes manually

```css
option.colored {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option class="colored">Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Or you can do this, have every :nth item colored in a specific list

```css
.coloredOption option:nth-child(2n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="coloredOption">
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
     <option>Option 3</option>
     <option>Option 4</option>
     <option>Option 5</option>
     <option>Option 6</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I though I did this on first try but it didn't work. I just realize that I didn't do ctrl F5 to refresh the cache.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to customize any types of check boxes(including select/options). We usually create divs that are look like we want and we tie this divs with our select/checkboxes with help of JavaScript