# Overwrite select option to add color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

i have this value in my chosen

```
 <select class="chosen-select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

the goal is to overwrite the value text to "Option(need red color) 1(stay black)"

how can achieve this?

Comment: Please also post the code that you have tried after doing some research.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add a clear example of what you want exactly?  Should option value change or option's name?

Comment: ok wait i will update this thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635317/how-do-change-the-color-of-the-select-boxs-option-text try this, similar requirement.