# Select drop down width - Chrome issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, drop-down-menu, width

I would like to control `<option>` list width of `<select>` drop down. By default, browser calculates larger text in the `<option>` and accommodes drop down. It doesn't look good in sites. I had tried the following CSS snippet and found working in FF.

```
select{
    width : 120px;
}
select option {
    width : 90px;
}
```

The only trouble causer is Chrome. Could u let me know if any workarounds.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tamilselvan/pDtwE/)

Comment: Windows XP SP2, Google Chrome 25.0, Firefox 12.0

Comment: related, but unanswered thread: [CSS Select Dropdown Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/cssselect-dropdown-option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling it didn't turn out for me. I've only script option left out. The following code does the trick..

```
/* To trim the charaters in the option list */
    var optLen = $('#country option').size();
    //console.log("Total length is :" +optLen);
    for(var i=0; i<optLen; i++){
        var txt = $('#country option').eq(i).text();
        //alert(txt);
        txt = txt.substring(0,20);
        //alert(txt);
        $('#country option').eq(i).text(txt);
    }
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tamilselvan/pDtwE/47/)