# Dynamically truncate <option> text to fit <select> list

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

By default, the selector list shown for a `<select></select>` element will be as wide as the widest `<option></option>` child it contains. If I hardcode the width of the select tag with CSS to make it more narrow, the widest option is truncated in the display.

I want to trim down the option text to fit the selection list, appending <sub>...</sub> (ellipsis) to show that it's truncated when the option is selected, however, when I expand the dropdown I want the text in the dropdown to be full width, without trailing ellipsis.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: @clearlight I'm not sure the new title is what I want. I need the width of the option tag to be fixed and the text to be trimmed down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `css` and `jQuery` :

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).find('option').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
select,
option.selected {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
</select>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tpbsdy91/)

Comment: superb solution, afaict

Comment: I concur that this is a superb solution. To extend on this though, you can simply use `option:checked` instead of `option.selected`, and avoid the jQuery at all :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes its true, but it will change on `hover` too, not just selected;

Comment: Only setting the width of the select element has any effect in Chrome/Mac. All the other css properties and javascript do nothing.

Comment: @Doamon.s thanks alot, but I can't see the ellipsis in your demo.

Comment: @LăngBùi Okay, if you are using chrome, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15245638/3183699

Comment: Solution for chrome can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26627224/4743939

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
option {
  width: 200px; // Adjustable
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

That will automatically force the select options to be the specified width, and convert any 'overflowing' text to ellipsis that remains within the bounds :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: No bearing in Chrome/Mac

Comment: Works for me on Chrome 108/macOS 12.4 Monterey.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for chrome here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26627224/4743939

Using this approach, the caret icon in select tag will disappear, so you might want to use a background image for it.