# How do I change the font-size of an <option> element within <select>?

Tags: html, css

I have built [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZEx9/) as an example of what I am doing.

What I am trying to do works fine in Firefox. With the font-size being **14px** when you open up the select options.

However looking at it in Google Chrome it picks the inherited font-size of **34px**.

I am ideally looking for the select options to be font size **14px**.

Is this possible to do?

I am willing to make any relevant fixes in jQuery should they be required.

Thanks

Code Listed Below......

```css
.styled-select {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 74px;
    float: left;
    width: 365px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: url(http://i50.tinypic.com/9ldb8j.png) no-repeat right center #5c5c5c;
}

.styled-select select {
    font-size: 34px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 70px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.styled-select option.service-small {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
    <select class="service-area" name="service-area">
        <option selected="selected" class="service-small">Service area?</option>
        <option class="service-small">Volunteering</option>
    <option class="service-small">Partnership &amp; Support</option>
        <option class="service-small">Business Services</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a select tag's option element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element)

Comment: I know this is a an old Q&A (~2013), but I wanted to share a great solution I just found that really works on all (most) browsers: [Pure CSS select dropdown style – override the default select dropdown styles with CSS](http://robido.com/css/pure-css-select-dropdown-style-override-the-default-select-dropdown-styles-with-css/) Posted on September 22, 2015 by Jeff Hays @ robido.com I found this stackoverflow Q&A first, so wanted to share what I found with others who may come across this later.

Comment: You said in the question that this works in Firefox, but I don't think it does work in Firefox any more.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One solution could be to wrap the options inside [**optgroup**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp):

```css
optgroup { font-size:40px; }
```

```html
<select>
  <optgroup>
    <option selected="selected" class="service-small">Service area?</option>
    <option class="service-small">Volunteering</option>
    <option class="service-small">Partnership &amp; Support</option>
    <option class="service-small">Business Services</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: It worked in Chrome (v28 I believe), Safari, IE etc at the time. I'll have to try find out where the bug report for it is

Comment: works on Chrome but IE11. I guess we cannot change the styles of the Option HTML tag

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on latest version of Chrome, any suggestions?

Comment: It does seem to work in both Firefox and Chrome for me (it changes the font size of just the options, not the <select> control)

Comment: not working for me in Chrome 95

Answer (score 18):

Like most form controls in HTML, the results of applying CSS to `<select>` and `<option>` elements vary a lot between browsers. Chrome, as you've found, won't let you apply and font styles to an `<option>` element directly --- if you do Inspect Element on it, you'll see the `font-size: 14px` declaration is crossed through as if it's been overridden by the cascade, but it's actually because Chrome is ignoring it.

However, Chrome *will* let you apply font styles to the [`<optgroup>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup), so to achieve the result you want you can wrap all the `<option>`s in an `<optgroup>` and then apply your font styles to a `.styled-select optgroup` selector. If you want the optgroup sans-label, you may have to do some clever CSS with positioning or something to hide the white area at the top where the label would be shown, but that should be possible.

Forked to a new JSFiddle to show you what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/zRtbZ/

Comment: no longer works on Chrome 109 :(

Answer (score 4):

```
.service-small option {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
```

I think it because you used .styled-select in start of the class code.

Comment: the setting of option font-size doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but none of these worked for me on `Safari` in 2022.

I used this:

```css
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

After the first 3 lines, all the css worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I applied the style to the `<option>` tag directly.

For exmaple, I was creating my own text editor and I want to show a select menu to select the header type. I want to show each option with the font-size of each option.
For example, if the first option is **Header 1**, then I want the word Header 1 in h1 font size. So, I used the class `h1` of bootstrap directly on the option tag.

```
<option value="h1" class="h1"> Header 1 </option>
```

[image]