# Change Font-Family or Css Class of Particular Items in DropDownList

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

I have a DropDownlist(DDL) which is populated by Database from Client Side.

I want to change font-family or Change CSS Class of particular items in DDL depending on some conditions (on DataValue Field basis of DDL).

I have tried following code:

```
protected void ddlAuthor1_OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in ddlAuthor1.Items)
    {
        if (int.Parse(item.Value) == 1)
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "font-family:AmrLipi;");
        }
    }
    upBookEntryForm.Update();

}
```

But it didnot work for me. I tried this code in OnDataBound event also but no success.

Please Help me on this issue

Comment: try this > item.Attributes.Add("style", "font-family:'AmrLipi',Arial;");

Comment: Hi Amit, whats the difference in my code and your code??

Comment: Note, that adding font styling to individual <option> tags in a <select> dropdownlist is not supported.  You might be able to get a similar effect by wrapping then in a <optgroup>.  More discussion in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830115/select-option-font-size)

Comment: wrapping 'AmrLipi' with single quote + adding Arial for backup font

Comment: [This could also help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)