# Make select option font-size the same as its container, without specifying a px/pt unit

Tags: css, html, forms

This must be a duplicate, but I can only find [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830115/select-option-font-size) where font sizes have been explicitly defined in CSS.  Here I am using the browser default font size.

I've noticed that in Firefox/IE11/Edge that the default font size is smaller in a list's `option` element, than what is used by default in the containing `label`, or parent container:

[image: Option font size] [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh8awoL2/)

No doubt its in the HMTL5 spec's, which is fine.  The question is, is it possible to make the font size the same (relatively) as it's containing label (so there is no shrinkage in size) without specifying a font-size (e.g. 16px)?  So, the word "Select" and the word "Foo" would be the same font size.

I've tried both...

```
select {font-size:1em;}
select {font-size:100%;}
```

...without success.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with `1em`? Is it a particular browser? I tried [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yywhnvyv/) in Chrome and IE11 and it appears the correct size.

Comment: In Chrome for me, "Foo" is definitely a smaller font size than "Select"

Comment: That's weird. When I use `font-size: 1em;` it is the exact same size. [Fiddle for proof](https://jsfiddle.net/yywhnvyv/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
label {
 font-size:1em;
}

select{
  font-size:inherit;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
 }
```

This will make them the same size without specifying a unit.

Comment: `font-size:inherit;` indeed does work perfectly, thank you.  Why the `appearance:none` though?

Comment: In fact, it even works without specifying a font size on the label (see https://jsfiddle.net/82fk3bv4/1/)

Comment: Although bizarely Firefox doesn't properly render the border when the down arrow is clicked to reveal the list item... [Reported bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?bug_id=924068&list_id=12887892]