# Font size of select options element text in html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Kindly assist on how to increase font size of text in option in select element in html.
I want to increase the size of select options "Not Satisfied, Satisfied and Very Satisfied" because it looks small in android browsers.

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="selection" style="height:80px; width:300px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <option value="not satisfied">Not Satisfied</option>
        <option value="satisfied">Satisfied</option>
        <option value="very satified">Very Satisfied</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the font-size of an <option> element within <select>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830115/how-do-i-change-the-font-size-of-an-option-element-within-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase by default selected option's font size by adding font-size in select. For increasing the select option's font size, keep options in optgroup and in css make a class called optgroup and fixed a font size.

```css
optgroup { font-size:40px; }
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="selection" style="height:80px; width:300px; vertical-align: middle;font-size: 40px;">
      <optgroup>
        <option value="not satisfied">Not Satisfied</option>
        <option value="satisfied">Satisfied</option>
        <option value="very satified">Very Satisfied</option>
       </optgroup>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add css `font-size` property to select element this will increase the size of text.

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="selection" style="height:80px; width:300px; vertical-align: middle;font-size:40px;">
        <option value="not satisfied">Not Satisfied</option>
        <option value="satisfied">Satisfied</option>
        <option value="very satified">Very Satisfied</option>
    </select>
</form>
```