# CSS: Dropdown option text color not working on Mac OS X

Tags: html, css, macos, cross-browser

I want to set the color of the dropdown options text with value 1 to red.

My HTML dropdown:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$TelephoneDD" id="MainContent_TelephoneDD" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">33534543534</option>
    <option value="1">78678678678</option>
    <option value="0">99923444445</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```css
#MainContent_TelephoneDD option[value="1"] {
  color: red;
}
```

This works in most of the browsers except in Chrome and Safari under Mac OS X.

**Q:** How can I make the dropdown options text color to red if the option value is 1 to work in Chrome under Mac OS X ?

Comment: can't you do it inline in HTML ?

Comment: Tried inline, doesn't work in mac OS X

Comment: '<option style="color:red" value="1">33534543534</option>' it's impossible to not work cross-browser.

Comment: see the last 2 paragraphs from https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/ ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Styling of `<option>` tags is not currently supported by WebKit browsers on Mac OS X. You may find some more ideas here: [Pure CSS solution to styling specific <select> options in webkit based browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365529/pure-css-solution-to-styling-specific-select-options-in-webkit-based-browsers).