# option:disabled css style does not works on Chrome and Safari for MAC

Tags: css, google-chrome

I can not change color for a disabled option on Chrome and Safari for MAC OSx. On firefox this code works. How can i override styles cross browser?

```css
option:disabled {
  color: #a69474;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option disabled value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works fine on chrome in my test. I did exacly as you did.

Comment: on my mac does not works maybe on windows works?

Comment: Put that in your question also. That you tested it on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine in chrome

```css
option:disabled {
        color: #a69474;
    }
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option disabled value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7qukoa8/). It works in Chrome but not Safari or Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

> Styling of  tags is not currently supported by WebKit browsers on Mac OS X. You may find some more ideas here: Pure CSS solution to styling specific  options in webkit based browsers?.

source: [CSS: Dropdown option text color not working on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974069/css-dropdown-option-text-color-not-working-on-mac-os-x)