# HTML change font color of text in option with CSS (Mac OS, Chrome)

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I attempted to change the color of an option like this but doesn't seem to change the color specified in the style. What am I missing here?

```html
<select name="test" >
  <option value="green" style="color:green;">this is green</option>
  <option value="red" style="color:red;">this is red</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Screenshot of the result running on my computer Mac OS (Chrome Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)) 
[image]

Comment: what you want ?? where you style the color

Comment: @bluefishy - It changes for me :)

Comment: E.g. style="color:green;" should turn the "this is green" text into green color

Comment: @SudiptaMondal what browser are you using?

Comment: its work proper..!

Comment: @BlueFishy - Firefox. Also works in chrome. Do you want the color to change for the selected option ? If yes, you might have to use JS. to change the color property of the `<select>` tag as per the color available in the child options

Comment: on Mac Chrome it doesn't work and it make sense.. On mobile it will not work too. You can use custom dropdown such as bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Dropdown option text color not working on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974069/css-dropdown-option-text-color-not-working-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 01**

Give this a try, it is effectively the same, but see if chrome on mac is happy with this :-)

```js
function selectionChanged(){
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('test');
    var selectedOption = selectElement.selectedIndex;
    selectElement.style.color = selectElement.options[selectedOption].value;
}
```

```html
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="selectionChanged()" style="color: green">
    <option value="green" style="color:green;">this is green</option>
    <option value="red" style="color:red;">this is red</option>
</select>
```

**Original answer:**

Perhaps what you need is....

```html
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="document.getElementById('test').style.color = document.getElementById('test').options[document.getElementById('test').selectedIndex].value" style="color: green">
  <option value="green" style="color:green;">this is green</option>
  <option value="red" style="color:red;">this is red</option>
</select>
```

1. Note that the green color is hard-coded for `select` element since the first / default option is green
2. and then `onchange` of select will re-apply the style based on selected option. (You could also create a specific function in JS, but this code will do the trick if your requirements are not going to grow)

Comment: The OP using mac + Chrome. Have you tested on this environment?

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS (Chrome). But it works in Firefox

Comment: Ah, my bad, I don't have access to mac, It worked for me on chrome Windows. Perhaps I will update an answer soon with alternate approach if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the color of the select based on the selection. Therefore;

```html
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="changeColor()">
  <option value="green" style="color:green;">this is green</option>
  <option value="red" style="color:red;">this is red</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = document.getElementById("test").value;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

You could try to use colour code instead of "Red" / "Green"

Refer to below colour code,
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

Try below coding,

```
<font color="#FF0000">This is some text!</font>
```

Comment: With css **HTML change font color of text in option with CSS**

Comment: The `font` element has been deprecated for years (obsoleted in HTML5). Do not use or recommend it.