# How do you style a select option on OSX Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, macos, microsoft-edge

CSS does not seem to work on the option tag on Microsoft Edge for Mac OSX.

Is there a trick to change the text color or background?

All the other browsers work.
Testing on Version 107.0.1418.24 (Official build) (arm64).

```
<html>
<body>
    <select>
        <option id="red" style="color:red;">Red</option>
        <option id="blue" style="color:blue;">Blue</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: colors not working]

Comment: Can you share some code? also, what microsoft edge version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test on Chrome for Mac OSX, it has the same issue. I searched and found that it's a known issue of Mac OS. You can refer to [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974069/css-dropdown-option-text-color-not-working-on-mac-os-x) and [this issue report link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1227186).

There's no solution to style the `<option>` for WebKit browsers on Mac OS for now as it is provided by the native system select. If you really need to use styled `<option>` on Mac OS, I'm afraid you can only write your own select component using `<ul>`,`<li>` and style them using CSS.

Comment: thats literally heartbreaking news, I dont suppose their is a recent update to solve this ?