# Select Option Dropdown color Changed in Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, next.js, select

While using select in nextjs for the Gender,
In windows, the background color is white but
In Mac, the background color is gray Why?

My code:

```
<select
   class="form-control"
   id="exampleFormControlSelect1"
   value={details.gender}
   onChange={handleDetails}
   name="gender"
>
   <option value="Male">Male</option>
   <option value="Female">Female</option>
   <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

**My Windows Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzqt5.png)

**My Mac Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5ng8.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313577/9142870

Comment: any official document, client need that