# How to override the input[type="select"] text colour in IOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, contact-form

I'm working on a contact form where the select inputs are designed to have white text on a black background. The desired styles are being applied correctly in every instance except when accessed via Safari or Firefox on either an iPhone or iPad.

The relevant CSS Script is as follows:

```
select{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Is there a particular reason that these browsers may not be processing this style? And how would I circumnavigate it?

*edited as both Firefox and Safari express this same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of styling is not currently supported by WebKit browsers on Mac OS X. You may find some more ideas here: [Pure CSS solution to styling specific  options in Webkit based browsers?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365529/pure-css-solution-to-styling-specific-select-options-in-webkit-based-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling the option?

```
select option {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, James! I've just updated the script but it's had no impact, unfortunately..

Comment: @waldrus iOS does not allow for the styling of `<select>` inputs in Safari. See this link for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006647/list-of-known-safari-on-ipad-differences-over-desktop-safari

Comment: @Mike Hermary This appears to no longer be the case, at least on the current version of iOS Safari. Setting `color` on the select element will successfully change the colour of the text in the select box.