# How can I apply css to elements created with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the text colour of certain options in a  but it is not working. none are red

```
    var style="color:red" 
    $('#newuserSelect')
        .append($('<option>', {
                value: "0",
                title: "hello",
                style: style
            })
            .text("my text"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDYEd/  the colour is black when it should be red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property name to use is "css", not "style". Also the value should be an object whose properties are the CSS properties to set.

```
$('#newuserSelect')
    .append($('<option>', {
            value: "0",
            title: "hello",
            css: { color: "red" }
        })
        .text("my text"));
```

You can, incidentally set the text with that initialization object too:

```
$('#newuserSelect')
    .append($('<option>', {
            value: "0",
            title: "hello",
            css: { color: "red" },
            text: "my text"
        })
    );
```

Now, [this does work](http://jsfiddle.net/eJmb3/), but it's important to note that when you're looking at the page with the `<select>` element not "open", you're not looking at the `<option>` elements. If you want the selected text to be red, then you need to also style the `<select>` element itself. When there's only one `<option>`, the `<select>` cannot be "opened" so you *never* see the style of the `<option>`.

I can't recall exactly but it may be the case that IE, or old versions of it anyway, won't pay attention to styles on `<option>` elements. IE `<select>` was implemented in a really weird way in old versions.

Comment: can a option element be styled

Comment: Well when the text is in the `<select>` widget, it's style comes from the `<select>` element's style.

Comment: @ArunPJohny works as expected, maybe OP wants the color of select instead

Comment: @ArunPJohny check the fiddle I linked in the answer. The style of the `<select>` element is what's important when the widget is not "open" so that you can see the options. When there's only one option, the style of the option element has no effect.

Comment: @ArunPJohny in chrome too

Comment: yes it is working I was checking with 1 element where the highlighted color was hiding the red

Comment: Actually, `style` is a valid attribute, and would work just fine with a valid string -> http://jsfiddle.net/9s3cW/

Comment: @adeneo yes I realize that that's true, but it seems ugly to me to do it that way. That's just an aesthetic opinion however and so nobody should feel obliged to pay attention to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `$(xyz).append(abc)` will return the object of `xyz` not `abc`. And by the way, The proper way to set the css for an element is to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function. Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for full reference.

So I would suggest you to use .appendTo in your current context. That will fit your need. Unlike [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) will return the object of xyz [`$(xyz).appendTo(abc)`]

Try this,

```
$('<option>', { value: "0", title: "hello" })
.appendTo('#newuserSelect')
.text('my text')
.css({color:'red'});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4tvTh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why calling jQuery to create this tiny piece of HTML?

```
$('#newuserSelect').append(
    '<option value="0" title="hello" style="color:red">my text</option>'
);
```

Comment: what if your value, title and text are dynamic ie not hard coded? then you'll need to break and canctinate your string like "...title=\\""+title+"'"~!!!@"£$"£!!!$~"£%@

Comment: @code578841441 Give a live example where this is actually a problem.

Comment: each method has it's advantages and disadvantages. What you see as ugly code may look clean to someone else. I never use the `$("html",{options})` syntax because i find it looks ugly. Though, i also generally don't create html using jquery very often.

Answer (score -1):

Your JavaScript is fine. You can't color individual options with CSS. This is the output of your original fiddle!

[image: This is your original fiddle]

Edited:
CSS Text color not taking effect in Chrome 31 for OSX Mavericks
[image]

[image]

Comment: [This is simply not correct.](http://jsfiddle.net/eJmb3/) (Well, the part about setting "style" is correct, though I wouldn't recommend messing with element styles that way.)

Comment: maybe not fully cross browser but for sure, in some, option can be stylized

Comment: Pointy, what are you talking about. I'm in Chrome 31 and coloring text isn't supported. Nice try. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203491/448865

Comment: Your JavaScript is fine!!

Comment: @cpreid check my fiddle and make sure you click the `<select>` to  open it up.

Comment: Ya man, checked it, text color does not get applied in Chrome!

Comment: @cpreid which OS? Works here chrome 31 Win 7

Comment: Chrome 31 on OSX Mavericks

Comment: At least state your sentence correctly. "You can't color individual options with CSS" means you can not do it at all, but definitely you can. You should say at least you can not for some browsers.

Comment: You might be right @cpreid, a screenshot (of the viewport) could prove it though. Edit your answer then I'll be able to remove my downvote. Cross browser testing is boring :D

Comment: Yeah, I should have phrased differently. As far as I can tell, the original JavaScript was never the issue - take a look at the screenshot i included.

Comment: Haha, cross-browser testing, always a blast :)