# How do you change the font size for JUST the selected option in <select> elements in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How do you change the font-size for JUST the selected option of select (dropdown) menus (that shows when the dropdown menu is closed), without effecting the other option items that appear when the dropdown menu is opened? **Specifically, for desktop Chrome**.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

See how the font sizes are different?

Here's what I've tried:

**HTML:**

```
<select>
  <optgroup style="font-size: 8px !important;">
    <option value="option1">Option #1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option #2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option #3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 50px;
}
select option {
    font-size: 8px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/annablabber/exp1e1x6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `:checked` css [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked)

```
option { color: blue; }
option:checked { color: green; }
```

Demo (using your markup), when option #3 selected:

[image: when option #3 chosen]

Comment: That's not working for me. I'm using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: It's working for me, I'm using Chrome 40 on Linux

Comment: Bummer! It looks like that's the functionality I want... but the client uses Chrome/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select>
  <optgroup>
      <option class="classname" value="option1">Option #1</option>
      <option class="classname" value="option2">Option #2</option>
      <option class="classname" value="option3">Option #3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select>
  <optgroup>
      <option value="option1">Option #1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option #2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option #3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
option.classname:checked { 
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

color: Color works on Google Chrome but does not work on Mozilla Firefox.

font-size: Font size does not work on Google Chrome but works on Mozilla Firefox(in a strange way)

*Quote: "Unfortunately, webkit browsers do not support styling of [option] tags yet."

I'm not sure it is still true.

*[How to style a select tag's option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/cssselect-dropdown-option)