# counties flags are not display in drop down in chrome and internet explorer browser

Tags: html, css

Images are not display in drop down in Chrome or Internet Explorer browser, but in Firefox browser they are displayed.
This is my css code:

```css
select.icon-menu option {
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom left;
padding-left:30px;
}
select#countries option[value="AF"] {
background-image:url(http://localhost/insurance/wp-content/plugins/arforms/flags/af.png);
}
select#countries option[value="AL"] {
background-image:url(http://localhost/insurance/wp-content/plugins/arforms/flags/al.png);
}
select#countries option[value="DZ"] {
background-image:url(http://localhost/insurance/wp-content/plugins/arforms/flags/dz.png);
}
select#countries option[value="AS"] {
background-image:url(http://localhost/insurance/wp-content/plugins/arforms/flags/as.png);
}
select#countries option[value="AD"] {
background-image:url(http://localhost/insurance/wp-content/plugins/arforms/flags/ad.png);
}

**This is my HTML code**
```

```html
<select name="countries" id="countries" class="icon-menu">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you have option to use jQuery plugin you will find this helpful - https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Comment: Thanks.. But Can you please run above snippet code on chrome browser drop down flags are not displayed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS+Select Dropdown Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/cssselect-dropdown-option)

Comment: as of now there is no much support for styling of <option> tag in  WebKit browsers

Comment: from google, check this http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags I don't know about cross-browser issues

Answer (score 0):

You can't style `<option>` tags in IE <9 and Chromium (except `color` and `background-color`). Options are just not meant to be styled.

You need to setup an alternative dropdown using a list (or something) similar.

Comment: Thanks....But....Do you have a any idea how to get all countries flag with countries name using only HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes Problem is solved**

**After using j-query code countries flags are display in all browser**