# How to show astrisk in select box option?

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there is any way to add asterisk after first option of select element?

Here is my **html**

```
<select class="form-control textyformcontrol">
   <option selected>Service area</option>
   <option>First Option</option>
   <option>Second Option</option>
   <option>Third Option</option>
</select>
```

Here is **css**

```
.textyformcontrol {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    height: auto;
}
```

All the options are having default white color.Thus how to add asterisk in red color through css?

Comment: use <p> between the asterisk and create a class inside the p where in the text are color red.

Comment: What do you mean by asterisk after the first option?

Comment: Like this " Service area * "  but  "*" should be in red color

Comment: First Option <p class="red">*</p>

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as all the options have global #fff color

Comment: how bout using style inside <p>?

Comment: tried the style inside. also aint working

Comment: This post recommends using Select2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

If you really want to customize your selects and options, I would go with that library.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution adds a red asterisk to each `option` element that does **not** have the `selected` attribute:

```
.textyformcontrol option[selected]:after {
  content: "";
}

.textyformcontrol option:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

Please see my demo [here](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/wJGyMK?editors=1100).

Comment: It is still all white, even with the other options

Comment: He is asking to make the asterisks red, which they are.

Comment: I mean even the asterisk is still red in my view.

Comment: Yes, the OP has asked for the asterisk to be red.

Comment: It was supposed to be white, not red, typo