# Mozilla Firefox issue. HTML select (drop-down menu) colouring of some options by their value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mozilla

I want to colour some options in select field (HTML) using JS/Jquery based on the values of the select options assigned. Here is my code:

```
        $('#selectField option[value="val1"]').css({ 'color': 'green' });
```

The code does its job perfectly in the Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but in Mozilla Firefox nothing happens. Has anybody an alternative for this browser to suggest? **The solution must be in JS not in CSS**. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a select tag's option element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element)

Comment: `#selectField option[value="val1"]{ color: green; }` in **CSS**

Comment: I must have it in JS not in CSS, because "val1" depens on a situation...I simplified the code above to highlight the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, it is done in **vanilla JS**:

```
var option = document.querySelectorAll("#selectField option");

for(var i = 0; i < option.length; i++){
    if(option[i].value === "val1"){
        option[i].style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

Hopefully, it helps :)

Comment: Nope :( Nothing hapens

Comment: @sawic try now?

Comment: This colours all options contained. Actually, colors onyl the selected option...but any of them, when selected.