# Letter-spacing on selectbox option not working

Tags: html, css

I tried to add some letter-spacing to the options of a selectbox. It seems that this do not work. To test if i touch the right element I added some color to the option.

[letter-spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW7Pi.png)

```css
select {
  letter-spacing:10px;
}

option {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="select" id="myselect">
   <option value="105">Option 1</option>
   <option value="106">Option 2</option>
   <option value="107">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

Comment: if you want to style dropdown selection, you will have to use some js lib to do so... There are many browsers, that complety ignores dropdown styling (in addition - mobile browsers will pop up the dropdown list with system visuals - fonts, sizes, color and so on)

Comment: letter spacing working with your fiddle.. i have checked with firefox, which browser do you got this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style dropdown selection, you will have to use some js lib to do so... There are many browsers, that complety ignore dropdown styling (in addition - mobile browsers will pop up the dropdown list with system visuals - fonts, sizes, color and so on)

Check out something like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Based-Drop-Down-Builder-EasyDropDown/

I personally don't recommend trying to style native `<select><option>` for the sake of visual integrity