# Text-decoration not working in Google chrome drop down (Select) option

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have the drop down list, and i want to strike through the specific option.
I'm using the below sample code, the red color is working fine but line-through is working in IE, but not working in chrome

```
<select>
<option>option 1</option>
<option style="text-decoration:line-through; color:red;">option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to apply this without any jquery or any other library, just by directly through JavaScript & css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

Comment: Apparently , this problem has been solved with a new update of Chrome.
Update your Chrome Version.

Comment: I'm using Google chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit), its not working. which version onwards it is supported

Answer (score 1):

A crude but working way to do this would be to just use a Unicode text generator like this one http://adamvarga.com/strike/. And it would end up working like this:

```html
    <select>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>s̶t̶r̶o̶k̶e̶n̶</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
    </select>
```

I am guessing it's a bug in chrome from what people before me wrote

Comment: @Mathiyazhagan If this helped you can mark it as a solution?