# How to add gradient background to a drop-down select option?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, background

I am wondering if it is possible to add style to an select option, that is shown as a drop-down, specially in the `::before` part. If I use the select as a list (with `size="5"`) works well. So, I think that with dropdown the `::before` element does not work:

```css
#list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#dropdown {
  width: 200px;
}

.gradient {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;                   
}

.gradient:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  top: -50%;
  left: -125%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5cb85c, transparent);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="one" class="gradient">One</option>    
      <option value="two">Two</option>    
      <option value="three" class="gradient">Three</option>    
      <option value="four">Four</option>    
    </select>
    
    <br/><br/>
    
    <select id="list" size="5">
      <option value="one" class="gradient">One</option>    
      <option value="two">Two</option>    
      <option value="three" class="gradient">Three</option>    
      <option value="four">Four</option>    
    </select>    
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: selects]

Is it possible? If not I will use a flat background color

Comment: Related if not dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

Answer (score -1):

This is only possible if you create your own drop-down menu from zero. A flat color is quite easy to implement, see https://gist.github.com/paulgriffin1989/8984254

Comment: Uhmm your example is for flat colorus right? I don´t see any gradient