# Checkbox not showing in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to simply display a checkbox in a bootstrap drop down but its just displays as blank.  It's a generic dropdown. Below I've shown my code and a few screenshots.  I feel like this is kinda bizarre and not sure if this is an angular thing or not.

stackblitz url:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45uk59
```

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label *ngIf='label!=null' for={{id}}>{{label}}}</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="{{id}}">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of content; let i = index" value="{{item.value}}">
      <span *ngIf='hasCheckbox === true'>
        <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}_i" /> &nbsp -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="item.text[{{i}}]" value="{{item.value}}" /> &nbsp;
      </span>
      {{item.text}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  content: DropDownContent[] = new Array<DropDownContent>();

  @Input() hasCheckbox:boolean = false;
  @Input() label:string  = null;
  @Input() id:string = 'defaultId'
  @Input() selectedId:number = -1;
  @Input() size: 'lg' | 'md' | 'sm' = 'lg';
  @Input() set contentInput(contentInput: DropDownContent[]) {
    if (contentInput) {
      this.content = contentInput.map(data => {
        return <DropDownContent>(data);
      });

      console.log(this.content);
    } else {
      //?
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.id)
  }
}

export class DropDownContent {
  value: number;
  text: string;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Comment: What is the value for Hascheckbox in ngIf ?if hasCheckbox is false then checkbox not displayed

Comment: @HiteshKansagara true

Comment: Can you make code snippet?

Comment: Not sure how, I'm very new to angular.  But i added the html in dev chrome console. It's actually showing the input checkbox in html, but not showing on my page?

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: No sir. And everything else in the page works as expected as well.

Comment: Show your component where you set hasCheckbox variable

Comment: I've added my component code. The hascheckbox seems to be working fine as it's triggering the ngif as true.

Comment: where you set the value true for hasCheckbox? I did not find in component

Comment: could you produce this issue in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @AmayaSan that's pretty neat, yeah here's the url.  Looks like the same issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45uk59

Comment: Hi @tshoemake please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element, i think this answers your question

Comment: @AmayaSan how?  Not sure how this applies to my code

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap divs in a form like sort of hack thing. not exactly what you want but it works:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div class="selectthingy">
    <div class="Box" onclick="showMeTheBoxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="checkboxselect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="boxes_wrapper">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" />SALSA</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" />MUMBA</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" />CHICKEN DANCE</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.selectthingy{
  width: 300px;
}

.Box {
  position: relative;
}

.Box select {
  width: 100%;
}

.checkboxselect {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#boxes_wrapper {
  display: none;
  border: 1px green solid;
}

#boxes_wrapper label {
  display: block;
}

#boxes_wrapper label:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
var boxthingy= false;

function showMeTheBoxes() {
  var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes_wrapper");
  if (!boxthingy) {
    boxes.style.display = "block";
    boxthingy= true;
  } else {
    boxes.style.display = "none";
    boxthingy= false;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/Archtects/pen/LmpLZr

Comment: I appreciate your response, but definitely not looking to do a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the checkbox, I suggest to use a plain text with emoji. It will be show and hidden with an ngIf with the help of `hasCheckbox` property combined with a new property to keep the track of selected elements:

```
export class DropDownContent {
  value: number;
  text: string;
  selected: boolean

}    
...
this.contentInput = [{
      "value": 0,
      "text": "Users",
      "selected": true
    },
    {...
```

So the template could be:

```
<select id="{{id}}" multiple>
    <option (dblclick)="item.selected=!item.selected" *ngFor="let item of content; let i = index" value="{{item.value}}">
      <span *ngIf="item.selected && hasCheckbox">✓</span>
      {{item.text}}
    </option>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ux2ka4)

Comment: hasCheckbox is a value being provided from a parent component. It's telling the generic dropdown component whether we need to have checkboxes or not.  If hasCheckbox is true, we're adding these checkboxes as a prefix to the item.  If it's false, we just add the item without checkbox.  I shortened the code for brevity.