# How to right align some part of text in <option> in <select>

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

**This is current look**:

[image]

**I expect this**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
   <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1123x1">S\J [1123]</option>
        <option value="562x1">Rib / Int. [562]</option>
        <option value="1123x3">Fleece [1123]</option>
    </select>
```

**Suggestion for select2 is also needed.**

Comment: try it like this  <option value="1123x1">S\J &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [1123]</option>

Comment: I don't think it is possible only with css why don't you try dropdown list

Comment: Character length are not always same so alignment break :'(

Comment: how to do that? @Viira

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969850/select-with-partial-text-align-at-right/50970109#50970109

Comment: monospace font and putting spaces between- is not a solution for me since the text length is irregular @TemaniAfif

Comment: it's not a solution, it's a *hack* to approximate as you won't find any solution if you work with native select element. You need to build your custom one or use a ready one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach to achieve that:

Using `select2`'s configuration options: [templateResult](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating), [templateSelection](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) and [escapeMarkup](https://select2.org/dropdown#built-in-escaping), the dropdown list can be manipulated as per the requirements.

I'm using sample data here:

```js
$('#example').select2({
  data: [
     {id: 'test1', text: 'January', subText: "Test1"},
      {id: 'test2', text: 'February', subText: "Test2"},
     {id: 'test3', text: 'March', subText: "Test3"}      
    ],
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
     return markup;
    },
    templateResult: function (d) {
     return '<span>'+d.text+'</span><span class="pull-right subtext">'+d.subText+'</span>';
    },
    templateSelection: function (d) {
     return d.text + ' ( ' + d.subText + ')';
    }
}).val('test2').trigger('change');
```

```css
.pull-right {
  float: right!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px"></select>
```

Quick explanation:

1. `templateSelection` is the way in which the list is rendered.
2. `templateResult` is the manner in which the selection option is displayed (try selection an option and you'll see how it works)
3. `escapeMarkup`, in short words, is to let select2 know that you're using HTML in the `templateResult` and `templateSelection` options.
4. Applying `pull-right` (corresponding CSS: `float: right;` to move the subtext to the right.

You can manipulate the options as per your requirement. I just wanted to show how it can be done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution, it's working. but how to assign value with the options?

Comment: You can set the value using `.val(<value>)` and trigger a change by default `.trigger('change')`. Edited the post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some better solution. this is my attempt to address your problem

```html
 <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1123x1">S\J &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;[1123]</option>
        <option value="562x1">Rib / Int.&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [562]</option>
        <option value="1123x3">Fleece&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [1123]</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It would make the list to look just like in the first screenshot the OP provided, would it not?

Comment: I am generating the `<option>`s from a PHP script, 
there may be hundreds of options

Comment: yes, but if the list is static then he can adjust the number of &nbsp; to get the desired result.

Comment: ok let me think of some workaround. this is quite tricky and a bit hard to achieve

Comment: @pravinnavle Refer to my answer above that uses select2's API options to align the text to the right and no fixed spaces (in case that helps)