# How to change default blue select option colour in CSS

Tags: css, select, menu, default, styling

[Simple Select Menu with blue background for options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaFbU.jpg)

What is the easiest way to change this default blue background when you hover over a select menu option? Can it be done with just CSS?

I've tried using :hover and :active selectors but it hasn't worked

Please help!

Comment: it's difficult to change style of option tag, it's easier to just make your own drop down list

Comment: @ChrisLi thank you, the thing is I don't host this dropdown, it's provided by a third party currency converter app and I can only change its styling via CSS.

So there is absolutely no way to change it?
It's the last tiny detail I need to get right and the website is good to go :p

Comment: heres a post on styling option tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is bound to `:focus`

```
select:focus {
   outline: 5px dotted green;
}
```

Here's the link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfuv1k09/3/

Comment: Thank you so much but I meant the options (in the dropdown) the background is blue and I want to change that to #000 and the text color stays as #fff

Comment: @LouayMadrid Madrid can you provide html code of the select?