# how to control select tag in chrome(Mac os)?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Although I only coded like this

```
<select>
    <option>all</option>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
</select>
```

my select box turns black when I click this.
this is picture before I clicked :

[image]

this is picture after I clicked : 
[image]

I want to make my select box like this:
[image]

is there anyone who knows what I should do ? :(

Comment: The options are rendered by the OS, you can't style them. You can replace the whole select with a JS solution, there are tons of libraries for this sort of stuff, chose one that fit's your need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a select tag's option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `appearance` property controls whether native styling applicable to your OS is used when drawing the field. Set it to `none` to disable native styling and do your own thing.

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

[This article](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/) may give you some more clues.

```css
select {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.better {  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #ff8200;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>This select is native to your OS</p>
<select>
    <option>all</option>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
</select>
<p>This select is styled with CSS</p>
<select class="better">
    <option>all</option>
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
</select>
```